# Perl Moving Target Defense, prevent code injection attacks

Tags: python, perl, security, code-injection

I was looking for modern solution about xss prevention, in this page the author uses a technique known as:

> Moving target defense (MTD), takes advantage of this gap between time
>   of check (exploit development) and time of use (exploit execution) by
>   randomizing (or mutating ) the environment after time of check and
>   before time of use
>
> in a manner that invalidates prerequisites of the exploits. For
>   example, by randomizing IP addresses of networks, RHM ensures that
>   exploits built based on scanning at a previous time (time of check)
>   will not be executable at a later time (time of use).

The author does mention about **Instruction Set Randomization**
ISR can be implemented to **prevent code injection attacks against Perl** scripts and SQL

Source:
https://www.hindawi.com/journals/scn/2019/2156906/

In the Book MTD Creating Asymmetric Uncertainty for Cyber Threats, about ISR:

> The concept of ISR is particularly versatile, and can be applied to
>   also protect such languages from command injection. We demonstrate its
>   applicability by implementing ISR for the Perl language.
>
> We randomize all of Perl’s keywords, operators, and function calls, by
>   appending a random 9-digit number (“tag”) suffix to each of them. For
>   example

```
foreach $k (sort keys %$tre) {
$v = $tre->{$k};
die ‘‘duplicate key $k\n’’
if defined $list{$k};
push @list, @{ $list{$k} };
}
```

by using “123456789” as the tag, becomes

```
foreach123456789 $k (sort123456789 keys123456789 %$tre)
{
$v =1234567889 $tre->{$k};
die123456789 "duplicate key $k\n"
if123456789 defined123456789 $list{$k};
push123456789 @list, @{ $list{$k} };
}
```

> Consequently, Perl code injected by an attacker will fail to execute,
>   since the parser will not recognize a plain-text (not randomized)
>   keyword, function, etc. We implemented the randomization by modifying
>   the Perl interpreter’s lexical analyzer to recognize keywords followed
>   by the correct tag.
>
> An attacker who does not know the instruction set cannot inject and
>   execute any code on the vulnerable system.
>
> Using this scheme, the administrator can periodically randomize the
>   system modules, without requiring any action from the user, while an
>   attacker will have to successfully guess the “tag” used by the system
>   to successfully run his malicious Perl script
>
> Other interpreted languages that could benefit from ISR include VBS,
>   **Python, and others**

Source Book:
https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461409762

My question, have you implemented something similar or equal for Perl or Python?

Comment: Neat, but unfortunately a bit off topic if it isn't something you need help with - this is more a topic for Reddit or Hacker News.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a discussion prompt, not a question with a single "best" answer.